# Amalgmating address details

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with several tabs each containing contact details. I want to compile a single contact list with street address details for each contact. Some of the tabs have contact and organisations details, but no street address. Other tabs have the complete information. There are multiple contacts working for the same organisation, but the org address may listed in one tab only. Can I use vlookup to do this?

Comment: [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you Marcucciboy2. Would you be able to tell me how to do it. I will have a crack but don't know if I will get very far.

Comment: definitely! there are lots of articles about this kind of things and lots of approaches to take. here's one place to start. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/10/31/excel-merge-tables-matching-columns/ once you get going you can update us and ask for more pointed help!

Comment: Thank you. I will have a go and see what happens.